# Water can/may still get in

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, pragmatics

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language , page 184, reads

> *May* is virtually excluded instead of *can* in *water can still get in*, partly by the likelihood of it being interpreted epistemically rather than
>   dynamically.

However, I cannot grasp any different effective meaning between both versions.

Comment: A problem with *may* is that is often used (and therefore understood) to mean "is allowed to", and so is not appropriate in the example you quote. There is no such problem with *can*. *Might* would also work there.

Comment: Contrast "I don't like the look of that roof! Water may get in." with 'The permeability of the membrane is intentional: oxygen may get in. Carbon dioxide may get in. Water may get in.'

Comment: The german angle helps a bit, as usual, but not terribly so. "mag" has come to mean "to like", perhaps ever has, in a passive aggressive voice approximately "do you may to fix that roof"; the subjunctive form "möchte" has become a lexeme on its own, ca "I'd like", more often in "you might fix that roof". pretty weird. So "water may come in" shouldn't have that subjunctive mood that it has, unless "may" is also a rebased lexeme, from a mood of "make" I guess, with s trace of "mighty power" (Ger *mach'* vs *Macht*). just look it up: [may](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/may)

Comment: "The main distinction between *kunnaną and *maganą is that the former deals with one's own capabilities, whereas the latter indicates ability due to favourable circumstances not under one's control" [wikt]

Comment: so if I say *you may*, then it's beyond your control!? You may thank me later for the info!

Comment: "May" and "can" are interchangeable in this case -- they both mean "it is possible" (since water is not something that could receive permission).  I think it is unwise to treat *CGEL* as an authority.

Comment: @GregLee  OP has missed out some important sections of the text here. Also CGEL are comparing informal and formal contexts as well as epistemic versus dynamic modality. what they actually say is that the *get* in the example coupled with the possibility of the sentence being interpreted epistemically (*Water may get in in the future* as opposed to *it sometimes gets in*) mean that you're unlikely to see such an example *in formal texts*). CamGEL's fine as an authority. OP's quotes are, however, not reliable.

Comment: @RosieF That's not what H&P are saying. But the OP has not quoted the book at all accurately (see my answer below).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have nicked your examples in my post. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @GregLee See my answer below, perhaps.

Comment: Araucaria bears watching. He may nick my examples. (I'm sure I've tried to ascertain whether that should be 'she', but being a m-h-functioning sociopath ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, you're safe. I'm a hairy bloke. [Your examples aren't though ...]

Comment: @Araucaria Safe, blokish, or hairy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a case of inadvertant misattribution by the Original Poster. Here is the actual text and its context:

[image]

<sup>*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Huddleston & Pullum (2002, p. 198)</sup>

As can be seen, Huddleston & Pullum are of course saying that such a sentence is perfectly fine. However, they note that we're unlikely to see this kind of sentence with *may* in a formal academic text. Although *may* is more formal than *can* here, *get in* is a rather informal idiom, and this particular example would be ambiguous with *may*, because it would likely  be interpreted as conveying epistemic instead of dynamic modality.

To see the difference between dynamic and epistemic meanings consider @Edwin Ashworth's  examples (one of which modified):

- **Epistemic**: *I don't like the look of that roof! Water may/might get in.* [epistemic deduction]
- **Dynamic**: *The permeability of the membrane is intentional: oxygen may get in. Carbon dioxide may get in. Water may get in.* [engineered dynamic possibility]

Notice that the text says absolutely nothing about deontic modality (i.e. any ideas about *permission* or anything like that).

Comment: Does _partly by the likelihood of it being interpreted epistemically rather than dynamically_ apply only to formal texts then?

Comment: @GJC No, not at all. But academics like to use very precise unambiguous language. The most important aspect here is *get in*. And notice that they do not say it is excluded - they say it is *virtually* excluded. (Which, if you think about it carefully means that it is not entirely excluded.)

Comment: Thats why I did not include the formality as a factor in my OP. Do native speakers (AmE vs BrE, if it's relevant) at least tend to maintain such a epistemic vs dynamic distinction?

Comment: @GJC We use *may/might/must/could* for epistemic modality, but not *can*. For epistemic modality we  do use ***can't***, however. When talking about epistemic modality (for example when making deductions), the opposite of *can't* is *must* not *can*.

Comment: @GJC "*That's why I did not include the formality as a factor in my OP.*" <-- But that's H&P's main point. You won't find that kind of sentence in formal writing even with more formal *may*.

Comment: That's ( in their own verbatim words)_"partly"_ H&P's main point,

Comment: @GJC  Not really, I don't think. The *partly* applies to each of the two reasons that you're unlikely to find it in a formal text, for example scientific writing. *Partly* because of informal *get in*, and *partly* because of the ambiguity. :-)

Comment: Does _partly by the likelihood of it being interpreted epistemically rather than dynamically_ apply only to formal texts then?

Comment: @GJC No, but scientific writing, for example, tries to avoid ambiguity. It's that particular example that makes an epistemic reading more likely (consider EA's examples). Given the right context, even their [22a] could be ambiguous between the two types of modality too. However, it would need to be quite a contrived situation. It's unlikely to be read that way normally.

Comment: Do native speakers (AmE vs BrE, if it's relevant) at least tend to maintain such a epistemic vs dynamic distinction in such examples? I do know about its different in scientific rigorous writing, but what about everyday speech?

Comment: Native speakers use all modals in English with several different types of modality. *May* and *can* are no different there. The only difference is that we don't generally use positive *can* for epistemic deductions. There are lost of modals that are excluded from certain types of modality in certain circumstances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100155/discussion-between-gjc-and-araucaria).

Comment: @GJC Would have to be tomorrow. Am a bit busy right now!

Comment: it's just a message with a link, that's all

Comment: @Araucaria As usual, *CGEL* makes little sense to me.  I have a hard time getting past the inappropriate terminology: "epistemic" refers to knowledge/belief, "alethic"  to necessity/possibility, "deontic" to obligation/permission.  "George may enter now." is ambiguous between alethic and deontic interpretations.  I don't know what the heck "dynamic" means (and I don't much care).